# React js input invalid while user types (I want to validate onBlur instead of onChange)

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, onblur

I've run into this problem a few times, and I'm looking for the "react way" to solve this.

### The Problem

A number field is temporarily invalid while the user is typing.  For example: "-45" is "-" and "2.3" is "2.".  The simplest validation example is just to parseFloat on the value.  Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/h55kruca/6/.  I'm looking for a way to validate onBlur instead of onChange, or something similar that achieves this.

Here's the JS in the example:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {number: 0}
    },    
    handleNumberChange: function(e) {
        var val = parseFloat(e.target.value);
        this.setState({number: val});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Editor number={this.state.number}
                    onNumberChange={this.handleNumberChange}
            />
        );
    }
});

var Editor = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form className="reactForm" >
                <input type='text'
                       value={this.props.number}
                       onChange={this.props.onNumberChange} />
                <span>{this.props.number}</span>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Note that the validation (`parseFloat` in this case) is happening in a parent or grandparent (and is ultimately stored on the server) and the Editor's `props.number` changes by user input **or from refreshed data from the server.**  This is the reason for a controlled component.

### Approach #0

I tried using onBlur instead of onChange, and react gave me this warning: `Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a 'value' prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use 'defaultValue'. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'.`

### Approach #1

Store a temporary "number" state that is actually a string.  Use that for whatever the user types in the input until onBlur.  I don't like this because of the amount of code needed to achieve something so simple.  I would probably end up creating a wrapper around each input element (painful to me).

### Approach #2

Wrap the input in a component that uses shouldComponentUpdate to stop updates until onBlur.  This again requires a wrapper around every input.

### Approach #3

Make the input an uncontrolled component by taking out the `value=`.  I haven't fully thought this through but I think I'll very quickly miss the features of the controlled component.  If there was a way to switch between controlled and uncontrolled onFocus and onBlur maybe that's my answer.

### Your Solution

There must be a simple way to solve this, or at least something in development within the react community, I just can't find anything.  How have you solved this?

Comment: I think my first example was confusing people because it was a little oversimplified.  I've swapped it out for a 2 layer example.  The `App` here should only set state.number to a valid number (not a string).

Comment: Any updates on this ? I have the same problem with an input that shouldn't have a value under a certain number. Validations in onChange obviously give weird behavior when you erase and the value goes lower than the minimum.

Comment: Ended up using Approach 1, quite painful for something so simple indeed. But I don't really see any other way at this point.

Comment: Yes @GeoffreyHug, I have as well resorted to approach 1 in multiple scenarios.  That temporary state variable really bothers me though! I haven't yet attempted to create the wrapper I mentioned.  Wouldn't you expect this to be a common issue within the react community?

Answer (score 0):

To validate `onBlur` you can change your input from this:

`<input type='text' value={this.state.number} onChange={this.handleNumberChange} />`

to this:

`<input type='text' onBlur={this.handleNumberChange} />`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Couldn't really follow what you were asking.

Comment: This is my approach #3, make this uncontrolled by removing value=.  I then need a way to update this as the data changes (the reason I want it controlled).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead of

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {number: 0}
    },    
    handleNumberChange: function(e) {
        var val = parseFloat(e.target.value);
        this.setState({number: val});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form className="reactForm" >
                <input type='text'
                       value={this.props.number}
                       onBlur={this.handleNumberChange} />
                <span>{this.state.number}</span>
            </form>
        );
    }
});

App.defaultProps = { number: 0 };

React.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Note:** To show value from some others then you have set it as like:

`React.render(
    <App number="10"/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);`

Any type of value you can send to the component as a props.

Comment: This is a approach you can use it.

Comment: I realised I left out an approach.  I've now added #0.  That was the first thing I tried, which is essentially what you've done.  I believe you meant to change `value=` to `defaultValue=` and make this an uncontrolled element which is my approach #3.

Comment: Yes I just separated/set the default value as a props and onBlur handled and update the state value.

Comment: I see that, and it works when the number is changed through the input, but it does not render a change in state.number from another source (like new data from the server).

Comment: For server side data you can Inject e.g 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { number: state.number }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App). This will convert state to props by redux.js.

Comment: Adding redux like you say only ensures props.number is updated.  But that props update will not update an uncontrolled (i.e. no `value` prop) <input>.

Comment: Also, if you say your suggestion uses a controlled <input> (because you actually do have a `value` prop on your <input>), then please refer to my Approach #0.  If you can solve that error then my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach is very close to working. Simply change value to defaultValue.

```
<input type='text' defaultValue={this.props.number} onChange={this.props.onNumberChange} />
```

Comment: This will validate on every character change, not when the user leaves the control